# Is "share the same sth with" unidirectional or bidirectional?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, grammaticality-in-context

Does the following sentence, mean the "ancestral communities" of A and B are exactly the same (bidirectional) or does it mean that only all "ancestral communities" of A are also "ancestral communities" of B, but B may have more "ancestral communities" (unidirectional)? If the structure is bidirectional, what other structure can I use to convey the unidirectional meaning?

If user A shares the same ancestral communities with user B, ...

Answer (score 1):

I think the phrase is bidirectional in itself. If you would like to convey the meaning that B may have more "ancestral communities", you should add a second sentence to provide more information on that matter.